# Un problemilla con javascript en el conteo de valores

Tags: php, javascript, html

estoy haciendo una herramienta que necesito para un juego, pero no sé como proceder, necesito que una función en javascript me sume todos los valores de cada linea por separado y lo muestre en el apartado puntuación de la derecha, pero me suma todos los valores de todas las filas en un solo número por culpa del nombre de id de estos inputs, pero necesito que solo sume filas independientes.

Adjunto una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando cambio el valor de un input (por equivocación) me lo vuelve a sumar, solo necesitaría que me sumara 1 valor de cada input y en el caso de haberme equivocado al cambiar el valor, que automáticamente se corrija.

Llevo un par de días pensando y seguramente sería más sencillo de lo que me imagino, pero estoy sin ideas ya.

Pongo el código de esta tabla:

```
            <?php

            if(isset($_POST['createTable']))
            {

                $maxPlayers = $_POST['players'];
        ?>
        <script>
            /* Sumar dos números. */
            function sumar(valor) {
                var total = 0;  
                valor = parseInt(valor); // Convertir el valor a un entero (número).

                total = document.getElementById('ptsTotal').innerHTML;

                // Aquí valido si hay un valor previo, si no hay datos, le pongo un cero "0".
                total = (total == null || total == undefined || total == "") ? 0 : total;

                /* Esta es la suma. */
                total = (parseInt(total) + parseInt(valor));

                // Colocar el resultado de la suma en el control "span".
                document.getElementById('ptsTotal').innerHTML = total;
            }
        </script>

        <table class="table table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Jugadores</th>
              <th scope="col">Partidas</th>
              <th scope="col">Puntuación final</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <?php
                $i=1;
                while($i <= $maxPlayers)
                {
            ?>

            <tr class="table-info">
              <th scope="row"><?php echo $_POST['jugador_'.$i]; ?></th>
              <td>


                          <div class="form-row align-items-center">
                            <?php

                            for($a = 1; $a <= 5; $a++)
                            {

                            ?>
                            <div id="player_<?php echo $a; ?>">
                            <div class="col-auto">

                                <select name="carrera_<?php echo $a; ?>" class="form-control-sm" id="exampleSelect1" onchange="sumar(this.value);">
                                    <option>0</option>
                                    <option value="8">1</option>
                                    <option value="7">2</option>
                                    <option value="6">3</option>
                                    <option value="5">4</option>
                                    <option value="4">5</option>
                                    <option value="3">6</option>
                                    <option value="2">7</option>
                                    <option value="1">8</option>
                                </select>

                            </div>

                            </div>

                            <?php } ?>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" style="margin-left:20px;" name="result_<?php echo $a; ?>">Resultado</button>



                            <br/>
                          </div>


              </td>
              <td><h3><span id="ptsTotal"></span></h3></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $i++;

                }
            ?>

          </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dices tienes un problema con el nombre de los inputs, te está cogiendo todos porque todos se llaman igual.

Prueba a diferenciar qué inputs pertenecen a cada jugador. Algo así:

```
// Añade el id del jugador en la casilla para poder llamarla
<span id="ptsTotal<?php echo $_POST['jugador_'.$i]?>"></span>

//Incluye el id del jugador en la llamada
onchange="sumar(<?php echo $_POST['jugador_'.$i]?>, this.value);"

//Utiliza el jugador como parámetro y llama a la correspondiente etiqueta
function sumar(jugador, valor) {
    // ...
    total = document.getElementById('ptsTotal' + jugador).innerHTML;
    // ..
     document.getElementById('ptsTotal' + jugador).innerHTML = total;
}
```